# Activity behind DialogFragment still accepts touches

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have the following `DialogFragment`

```
public class DetailItemFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {


@BindView(R.id.task_detail_name)
AppCompatTextView taskDetailNameText;
@BindView(R.id.task_detail_description)
AppCompatTextView taskDetailDescriptionText;
@BindView(R.id.task_detail_priority)
AppCompatTextView taskDetailPriorityText;
@BindView(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); //doesn't work
    dialog.setCancelable(true); //doesn't work
    return dialog;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_view, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    //Get the Json back and parse it as a Task
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    final String taskAsJson = bundle.getString("task");
    Task task = new Gson().fromJson(taskAsJson, Task.class);

    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.close);
    }
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);

    taskDetailNameText.setText(task.getName());
    taskDetailDescriptionText.setText(task.getDescription());
    taskDetailPriorityText.setText(task.getPriority().toString());

    return view;
}
```

I perform the Fragment transaction like so

```
//Put the clicked item into a Bundle for the next fragment to consume
DialogFragment detailItemFragment = new DetailItemFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("task", new Gson().toJson(mTaskListAdapter.getItem(position)));
detailItemFragment.setArguments(args);

getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
             .add(R.id.task_detail_fragment_container, detailItemFragment)
             .addToBackStack(null)
             .commit();
```

I'm trying to accomplish the following:
* On a tablet/large screen, this displays as a Dialog popup
* On a phone, it will display a fullscreen dialog (pretty much trying to replicate how Google Calendar handles opening event details)

This is what my `xlarge/activity_main.xml` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/task_detail_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="800dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:elevation="16dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/ToolbarStyle"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:title="@string/app_name"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/task_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_normal_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_normal_size"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_padding"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/add_black"
        app:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="@dimen/fab_pressed_elevation" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You'll notice I have a `FrameLayout` that is centered on the screen for loading the `DetailItemFragment` into. Maybe this isn't the correct way to do this--but I want to bring it up in case that turns out to be the issue.

This is what the `fragment_detail_view.xml` layout looks like

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/task_detail_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    tools:context="io.havoc.todo.view.fragments.DetailItemFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_tall_height"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/task_detail_name"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:gravity="start|bottom"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Task detail"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="86dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_margin"
            android:text="@string/hint_task_description"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/task_detail_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Description text"
            android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_margin"
            android:text="@string/hint_task_priority"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/task_detail_priority"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Priority"
            android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**The issue**

When the `DialogFragment` is open on a tablet, the `Activity` in the background still accepts touches (i.e. I can interact with the `Activity` as if the dialog wasn't even present); furthermore, I have no idea how to get the `DialogFragment` to dismiss when touching outside of it. I've tried the following:

- `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);` (in the `onCreateDialog()` method)
- `dialog.setCancelable(true);` (in the `onCreateDialog()` method)
- `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` (in the `onCreateDialog()` method)
- `getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); setCancelable(true);` (leads to `NullPointerExceptions`--performed in `onCreateView()` for the `DialogFragment`)

I've gone through all the other questions like this I could find and nothing has worked for me--so clearly I'm doing something wrong.

I appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

The `FrameLayout` (`task_detail_fragment_container`) you are adding your `DetailItemFragment` TO has a different size then the parent, which means it will not cover the entire layout:

```
...
        android:layout_width="800dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
...
```

To fix this, make `task_detail_fragment_container` the same size as the parent layout (`match_parent`) and cap the size of the dialog in the dialog layout by introducing another Layout after your `container` layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    tools:context="io.havoc.todo.view.fragments.DetailItemFragment">

     <FrameLayout
         andorid:width="800dp"
         android:height="400dp"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true">

         <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout ...
         //rest of your xlm here
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I already have that. The touches aren't going through the dialog--but I can touch items outside of the dialog.

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure what you're getting at. I updated the op to include the code for my `fragment_detail_view.xml` and it is already `clickable`

Comment: @Nxt3 It should have worked. If you're running into other issues, lets try to resolve them

Answer (score 0):

Change to `.dialog.setCancelable(false);`.

If it's a dialog with OK and Cancel buttons, you can use:

```
.setCancelable(closeActivity == true ? false : true)
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable(boolean) says `Sets whether this dialog is cancelable with the BACK key.`. How is that going to help?

Comment: I don't have any buttons; this is also already in the OP and I said it didn't work.

Comment: Back key isn't his problem! He says: "I can interact with the `Activity` as if the dialog wasn't even present".

Comment: When I say that, I mean I can interact with the Dialog and touches go to the Dialog--but any part of the visible background Activity can be interacted with while the Dialog stays present (i.e. it won't go away unless I manually close it)

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

with

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: Tried both of these and nothing changed.